# How is exception handled in transactional context with finally block?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, try-catch-finally

If i have transactional method like the one below, when is the finally block executed in case of transaction commit and rollback? For example if "persist some entity in database with hibernate" throws some hibernate exception which is true?

1) transaction rollback
2) finally block is executed

or

1) finally block is executed
2) transaction rollback

```
public void someTransactionalPersist(...) {
     try {
     // persist some entity in database with hibernate
     } finally {
        // do something 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both case finally block will executed [finally](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html).
sequence will be, If your try block throw exception then it will `rollback` first and then `finally` block will `executed`.

Comment: i doubt over rollback first then finally block, because transaction will be managed by aspects which will be around method someTransactionalPersist so after leaving execution of this method aspect will try to rollback, can you clarify why rollback first?

Comment: Rollback will called on event of any error. Finally block will always run and the last line of try block.

Comment: yes agree but rollback will be done by aspect so it will be after execution of method

Comment: @JigarParekh, Rollback will called inside the transaction, not to the whole method. and then your finally block get executed. That's way we close the session inside the finally block.

Comment: but i am assuming transaction is being managed by spring aspect which will be always around method so after excution completion of target, aspect will complete his job of commiting or rollback transaction.

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
    //This is executed if an exception is not thrown
} catch(Exception e){
    //This is executed if an exception is thrown
} finally{
    //This is executed regardless of which of the above was executed
}
```

Comment: Ye, i know that, but i am asking how thinks are happening in transactional context, where the exception is thrown after the method is completed and commit/rollback is down at the end of the method and if there is an exception it is injected with AOP.

Answer (score 0):

assuming someTransactionalPersist method is start point of transaction then if there is any exception in try block then first finally will be executed and if there is runtime exception thrown from finally block then spring will do rollback as default configuration.

if you want rollback for perticular exception then you have to configure `@Transactional` with `rollbackFor`.

if you want to manually mark transaction as rollback without further throwing exception/runtime exception then you have to do this in catch block `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly()`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the specification http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2

If there is no Exception, after the try has executed without errors, the finally block will be executed. If there is an error in try and there is a catch-block, catching that exception, the catch block is executed. Afterwards, the finally block will be executed.

If there is an error in the try block and there is no catch block, catching that exception, the finally block will be executed and your method will throw that uncaught exception.

So, the finally block will **always** be executed and will always be the last block, being executed.

Comment: the question is, when it is rolled back? after finally or after catch